# iMovie 10 - How to layer a background under a title?

Tags: video, imovie

I'm new to iMovie 10 and in my project I added a title clip with a duration of 60 seconds and I would like to add a background clip UNDER the title clip.  But when I select a background from the backgrounds and drag it into the timeline, the new background clip is layered above the title clip -- ie during replay the background is displayed over the title hiding the title underneath it.  Repositioning the background clip by dragging it under the title clip in the timeline does not work - the background clip snaps back to the top.  What to do?

Comment: I can't believe this isn't answered. I have the same problem. How can it not let you move it under the clip?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One (hacky) way I achieved this was by making sure the timeline is empty, then I added the needed background, and then added the clip (or title in your case), which was allowed to be added on top of the background.